# Unity Android app not showing in app list

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on an Android application on Unity. I'm almost at the end of the development but I started having a problem with the build of the app. **The problem is that despite the app is installed and works fine, it doesn't appear in the app list (but is installed).**

I basically was stuck in a problem and when I was trying solutions to fix it **I decided to export from unity to open the project in Android Studio**.
When you import a project from Unity, A.S. makes some changes (Maybe that's the problem), so I installed the app from Android studio but instead of fixing the problem I had, the app started to not show in the app list.

I've fixed the problem I had, but even now the app still not shows on the list, but I can run it and search it.

I tried to look for the problem but it seems that is not very common. I also tried to delete all of the app data from my phone, but still nothing. So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check is you bundle identifier is same
2. PlayerSettings > Enable build il2cpp Armv7 and 64bit build and donot split the build
3. Assign the keystore and assign password
4. Set the player setting SDK Card to Automatic
5. Make Sure your previous build is assigned with same keystore

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of 2 things:

1. You have same Bundle ID for this application with some other installed app on your phone. So rather than installing it gets updated.
2. Something wrong on your device side. Maybe some launcher setting that is hiding this application.

Try using some other phone or emulator.